# GroupBy using Linq with related Entity in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I need to group a list of questions by speaker using Linq:

```
public partial class Question
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Speaker")]
    public int Speaker_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Speaker Speaker { get; set; }
}

public partial class Speaker
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a list of Questions Grouped By Speaker:

```
   Question.Date  | Speaker.Name | Question.Description
```

I get here but it's not working:

```
db.Questions.Select(c => new
            {
               c.Date,
               c.Description,
               c.Speaker.Id
            })
            .ToList()
            .GroupBy(c => new { c.Id, c.Date, c.Description })
            .Select(g => new Question
            {
                Date = g.Key.Date,
                Speaker = db.Spkeakers.Where(o => o.Id == g.Key.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                Description = g.Key.Description
            })
            .ToList());
```

It's sorting by Date and not grouping by Speaker.

Comment: What have you done so far.  This shows no effort on your part and is a "code this for me" question not a question about a problem.

Comment: Hi Hogan, I was editing the question with the code.

Comment: Does each row have a different date?

Comment: What a resume BTW Hogan, I'm impressed!!

Comment: @Patrick, so that's probably your problem.  You're trying to group by a column that is essentially a unique identifier for each row.

Comment: @StevenWexler yes I think you are correct, I sorted by Speaker_Id and everything seems ok, sorry to take your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're including Date (a DateTime type) in your group by clause.  There's a good chance that each of your rows has a different date.  If that property is true for your data, then grouping by date is essentially grouping by a unique identifier.  Instead, maybe try to group by a less granular date by grouping by day, month, year, etc.  Also, you could just group by speakerId and only order by date.

Comment: I can't sort by Speaker and then by Date ?

Comment: I think you're confusing group by with order by.

Comment: Perhaps writing the equivalent SQL will help you understand the difference between LINQ's group by and order by functionalities.  See http://www.codeducky.org/sql-queries-in-linq/#group-by.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I need to group by speaker, and in this group, order by date, is this make sence?

Comment: I don't think group by speaker id and order by date would work since there is a many to one relationship between date and speaker.  I guess you could use earliest date

Comment: If @Patrick wants to order by date within the groups then it should work well.  Otherwise, he can arbitrarily order by the earliest date in the group.  I'm not sure which behavior he wants, but I was thinking the first option.

Answer (score 0):

To order by speaker and date do this:

```
  var result =  db.Questions
                    .OrderBy(t => t.Speaker_Id)
                    .ThenBy(t => t.Date);
```

---

This is how you group by speakers and give a count:

```
  var result =  db.Questions
                    .GroupBy(t => t.Speaker_Id)
                    .Select(g => new { Speaker_Id = g.Key, count = g.Count() });
```

This is how you show this table ordered by date

```
  var result = db.Questions
                   .OrderBy(t => t.Date)
                   .Select(item => new { Date = item.Date, Name = item.Speaker.Name, D = item.Description });
```

Note, if you want a list of Questions as your result then the last select is not needed.

Comment: I think I have make a mistake here because I tried to sort by Speaker_Id and the list is has I wanted to be, so very sorry for my mistake and take your time.

Comment: oh... all you had to do was sort by speaker_id and do a select?

Comment: Yes it seems so, and has the records are inserted by time, they are listed by date after listing ordered by speaker

Comment: @Patrick - I edited the question to the correct way to get your results... you got lucky, as soon as you have more data in sql it will be more and more likely you will get unordered results.

Comment: At the moment I have db.Questions.ToList().OrderBy(q => q.Speaker_Id) do you think I will have problem with this one?

Comment: @Patrick You only have a problem if you want it to be ordered by date for each speaker.  It might show up that way for now but it won't always.